# SQL query accepting date parameter in MM-DD-YYYY format instead of DD-MM-YYYY

Tags: sql-server

Here is my stored procedure which accepts two date parameters, one for start date and second for end date. It gets a bunch of different data from joined tables:

```
@FromDate varchar(50),
@ToDate varchar (50)

SELECT DISTINCT 
    dbo.DefectInspection.DefectInspection_Id, 
    CONVERT(varchar(50), CAST(dbo.DefectInspection.DefectInspection_CreatedDate AS date), 34) AS CreatedDate
FROM           
    (bunch of tables)
WHERE
    CAST(DefectInspection.DefectInspection_CreatedDate AS date) 
        BETWEEN CAST( @FromDate AS Date) AND CAST(@ToDate AS Date)
```

The issue is it will only return date if I input my dates as `MM-DD-YYYY` instead of the days firsts. This is an issue because the date style sent from client side is always DD-MM-YYYY

Using desired input: no data returedn

[image: Table W/o data]

Using month format - data returned

[image: Table With Date]

Comment: Dates have no format, they're binary values. Formats apply only when parsing strings into dates or formatting dates as strings for export or display. This means that `@FromDate varchar(50)` is a serious bug. Use the correct type instead, `date` or `datetime2`. If you only want the date part, use `@FromDate date`

Comment: What is `DefectInspection_CreatedDate`? Unless it's a date-related type, (ie `date`, `datetime2`, `datetimeoffset`, `datetime`) you have a very serious bug and no way to tell what's stored in that field. You have no way to tell what `04-07-2022` means, you can only assume and hope the client didn't use the wrong format. You can't use any indexes either, so all queries have to scan the entire table

Comment: TRY_PARSE  Please

Comment: Why not just use an unambiguous format for your literal date strings, and use a date (and time) data type? `yyyyMMdd` would be the "best" choice for a date, as it's unambiguous regardless of data type and language setting. If you need a date and time then use `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)` or `yyyyMMdd hh:mm:ss(.nnnnnnn)`, which are also completely unambiguous.

Comment: PARSE TRY_PARSE

Comment: CONVERT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16

Comment: CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

Comment: Select style which is your case (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles)

Comment: CAST could be used to change

Comment: PARSE is the best option

Comment: None CONVERT is old

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using SQL (and other languages) its best to use an unambiguous format such as `yyyy-mm-dd`

Also consider using the `DATE` type instead of `VARCHAR`

```
@FromDate DATE(50),
@ToDate DATE(50)
```

Comment: Parameter send from client side is in varchar. will that work?

Comment: SQL will always try and convert varchar to date. Pass yyyy-mm-dd from your client

Comment: I Converted the varchar into yyyy-mm-dd date format first then passed the parameter so this worked. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Though using the wrong datatypes is terrible, sometimes we all have to deal with issues which cannot be changed easily.

You can use:

```
DECLARE @fromDate AS varchar(50);
DECLARE @toDate AS varchar(50);
DECLARE @from AS date;
DECLARE @until AS date;

SET @fromDate = '09-01-2023';
SET @toDate = '10-01-2023';

SET @from = TRY_CONVERT(date, @fromDate, 105);
SET @until = TRY_CONVERT(date, @toDate, 105);

IF @from IS NULL OR @until IS NULL
    THROW 51000, 'Parameter is not a valid date ..', 0;
ELSE BEGIN
    SELECT DISTINCT 
        ...
    FROM           
        (bunch of tables)
    WHERE TRY_CONVERT(date, DefectInspection.DefectInspection_CreatedDate, 110) BETWEEN @from AND @until;
END;
```

[TRY_CONVERT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-convert-transact-sql) returns NULL if the parsing fails.
The 3rd parameter ([style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#date-and-time-styles)) 105 means format "dd-mm-yyyy" like you use it, 110 means "mm-dd-yyyy".